# What fields of arithmetic/algebraic geometry benefit from infinity/derived techniques?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry, model-categories, derived-categories

I'd like to get a better picture of how infinity/derived techniques become more important in algebraic/arithmetic geometry.

I'd therefore like to know:
What questions/subfields of algebraic/arithmetic geometry seem to (a) benefit the most of using infinity categories and derived AG techniques and (b) which questions/subfields seem to be especially well-suited to get "revolutionized" by the homotopical approach to mathematics, even though it may not yet happening at the moment.

I'm thinking of results like the [Exodromy paper](https://shifted-project.github.io/files/exodromy.pdf) and the [SHIFTED project](https://shifted-project.github.io/) in general (and I'd be very interested to get to know what's moreover planned in these cases).

For example: is it to be expected that these techniques could play an important role in anabelian(-ish) questions of arithmetic geometry, like for example some results of Exodromy suggest?

Comment: Why the (model-theory) tag? Did you mean (model-categories) by chance?

Comment: Oh yeah I did of course lol

Comment: No idea of what it is, can you give a concrete relevant example

Comment: I don't understand your question..

Comment: I'm not sure if this is an answer to your question, but there are a lot of conjectures involving derived categories and birational geometry. You could look at the survey paper by Kawamata, "Derived categories and birational geometry".

Comment: Mhm yeah that's of course interesting. Although I was more looking at applications of ideas involving simplicial schemes/Lurie's infinity categories..